# Insert and select from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i've a problem with my query. The problem is that: the file is correctly loaded in the uploads folder. But not in the database with the content of the textarea.

i ve created this table into my database with:

```
CREATE TABLE dati(article VARCHAR(30), photo VARCHAR(30))
```

this is my code (pick from internet)

```
 <?php
 //This is the directory where images will be saved 

 $target = "../image/"; 
 if(isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
 $target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 }
 $article = (isset($_POST['article'])); 
 $pic = (isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])); 

 // Connects to your Database 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 if (isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])) if (isset($_POST['article'])) {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO nome_tabella (photo, article) VALUES ('{$_FILES['photo']['name']}', '{$_POST['article']}'");  
 }
 //Writes the photo to the server 
  if(isset($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 


 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

I tried several times, but does not insert data into the database. What's wrong?

This is the code for read the results

```
<?php 
     //Retrieves data from MySQL 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'dati' (photo, article)") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
     echo "<div id='cover'>";
     echo "<img src='http://localhost/chiedifilm/image/".$info['photo']. "'>"; 
     echo "</div>";
     echo "" .$info['article']. "";
     echo "<hr>"; } ?>
```

It does not load the image name and the textarea tinymce.

Im sorry for my bad english, i don't speak it very well.

Comment: `("NSERT INTO nome_tabella ` missing an `I` - `("INSERT INTO nome_tabella ` - typo? That's one of the errors in your code. John showed you the other.

Comment: Your select statement isn't correct. It has multiple mistakes. Try: `SELECT photo, article FROM dati `

Comment: +1 ...ah yes, spotted that after @JohnConde darn quotes etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO because mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: @MajorCaiger No problemo on your answer. However, you had a syntax error. Not sure if you're going to fix and undelete.

Comment: " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dati'' at line 1 " ...

Comment: The table you want to insert into, is it `nome_tabella` or `dati`? @SardaFilm

Comment: I have corrected. 
I removed the quotes but it didn't work...

Comment: Try this `("INSERT INTO dati (photo, article) VALUES ('{$_FILES['photo']['name']}', '{$_POST['article']}'")` and you may need to increase `VARCHAR(30)` to higher numbers.

Comment: Anything...don't work...the sql is right? CREATE TABLE dati(article VARCHAR(30), photo VARCHAR(30))


I try to increase the VARCHAR but "nada" lol... @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

Check your code:

```
 //Writes the information to the database 
 if (isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])) if (isset($_POST['article'])) {
 mysql_query("**NSERT** INTO nome_tabella (photo, article) VALUES ('{$_FILES['photo']['name']}', '{$_POST['article']}'");  
 }
```

where's "I" on INSERT statement

regards